# Using “not”before a noun in this context

Tags: grammar

I am translating a poetry into English. is “not” fine to use in this way

> Not desire, not love, not passion and not even faithfulness;
> nothing that person has except beauty!

I want to say: “desire, love, passion and faithfulness, she doesn’t have but beauty”

Comment: I hope you realise that in order to translate a text and produce something that's any good, you need to master the target language even better than what you'd need as the author of a similar text in the same language. Translating creative writing and especially poetry into any other language than your first is incredibly difficult and unadvisable.

Answer (score 1):

It works, except for the word order "nothing that person has except beauty", which would be better as "that person has nothing except beauty".

It's alright to repeat "not" that way, but another option might be

> Not desire, nor love, nor passion, nor even faithfulness...

Answer (score 1):

Translating *a poem* is very tricky because poetry often (successfully, and beautifully) goes against normal rules of grammar for artistic effect.

That said, your use of "not" before the nouns "desire", "love", etc. is fine and does not break rules. The second half of your sentence *is* technically ungrammatical though.

Being ungrammatical is not *necessarily* a problem in poetry, but this particular phrase,

> "nothing that person has except beauty"

sounds awkward to me. If you are inverting the word order in the clause (to start it off with the direct object ,"nothing"), it sounds better to me as *object-verb-subject*:

> "nothing does that person have except beauty"

Or best of all, to my ears, normal word order, (*subject-verb-object*):

> "that person has nothing except beauty"

That's my opinion, but I am not a poet.

But, to your question: the first half of the sentence, "Not desire, not love, ... not even faithfullness;" is OK, no problem.

Comment: You are correct, but as you point out, poetry is allowed to break the rules! So it says not, not, not, not, nothing to keep the structure consistent.

Comment: Ah, I definitely get what you mean. Inverting the word order to start the sentence with the direct object ("Nothing") is a pretty accepted thing in English when you want to get creative and break from routine. I just wanted to point out that the *typical* way of inverting the sentence would be (O-V-S) "Nothing *does* that person *have* ..." But again, I am no poet.